# know when SCNAction ends

Tags: ios, scenekit

How to write a completion handler for when the SCNAction ends? Or maybe just get notified when the action ends. Is is any way to know when the action ended? My last resort is to use custom `delay(delay: Double, closure:()->())` function with `delay` set to actions execution time, but that seems rather fragile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`runAction(_:completionHandler)` and `runAction(_:forKey:completionHandler)` accept closures. They're defined on the `SCNActionable` protocol, not `SCNAction`, so the documentation is easy to miss.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnactionable/1524219-runaction

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I totally missed it.